# AspNet5 beta8 preflight request from Firefox returns no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox, preflight

I have an AspNet5 beta8 website mydomain.com:80 and api running on  mydomain.com:81.
Only the port is different. I did configure Cors and it does work very well in IE11 and Chrome. Unfortunately I cannot make it work in Firefox version 42.

The difference is in requested content type by Firefox during the preflight request:

```
Firefox: OPTIONS 204 No Content, Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

to which api replies with json inside OPTIONS response.
This is followed by

```
GET 404 Not found. XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{15a3ffbb-ab25-4adc-a332-fe52135c1fa6} Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

I assume because Firefox got json instead of XML and got angry.

Both Chrome and IE11 work fine because they accept any content type during preflight request:

```
OPTIONS 204 No Content, Accept */* followed by GET results in status 200 OK.
```

Because AspNet5 by default does not include the XML serializer / formatter,

I tried to add it in the api like that:

```
services.AddMvc().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

Unfortunately this does not result in xml response to preflight request from Firefox. Api consistently sends json. I also tried to set the following:

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(
    options =>
    {
        options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
    });
```

No luck with that either...

How can I force api to reply with xml to preflight request from Firefox or force Firefox to request json inside OPTIONS request programmatically (I use Angular on the client side)?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to this problem based on XDomain javascript library available from here:
https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain

It can be easily integrated with Angular, handles CORS entirely in javascript and disables preflight requests in browsers (tested with IE11, Chrome and Firefox 42).

Website loads faster with xdomain because there is no overhead of preflight requests.